# Apache .htaccess rewrite all urls to https home page with exceptions that rewrite to https current page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite ALL http://www.example.com/* urls to https://www.example.com/ except some pages. I can get the catch all rewrite to work no problem:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

However, if I try to add the exceptions before the catch all home page forward, they do not work. Also, if I just try add them by themselves, (commenting out the previous rule), they do not work.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^/?products/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/products/$1 [R,L]
```

So, there are a few pages on the site I want to have simple http->https rewrites. 
If someone goes to `http://.../products` they should be forwarded to `https://.../products` for example.

Also, I want to make sure whatever rule I have works for `www.example.com/products` and `example.com/products`.

Comment: What are all your rules? Both of those work for me. There must be some ordering issue going on.

Comment: These are the last lines in the .htaccess file. Do I need to show my other rules that are above these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/products/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I don't know what is going on. I know this should work but it does not. This is a Drupal website though, so maybe it just won't. What I cannot understand for the life of me is why the blanket rewrite works and the specific one does not.

Comment: The rule must be at top of drupal .htaccess file, before drupal rules. If products directory exists, the .htaccess file with the rule must be out there, in the father directory.

Comment: Fair enough. I will look into this deeper and report my findings or just accept this answer as correct, because it is as far as I can tell.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much, that rule needed to go first!